# Liquibase formatted sql auto generated id

Tags: java, liquibase

Is it possible to use something auto generated as id of changeset?
For example:

```
—changeset myName:${currentDate} context:myContext failOnError:true
```

Comment: I answered your question, but perhaps you could explain why you want to do this - what is the real goal? There may be a way to solve that problem.

Comment: I have a sql file with table creation scripts. It runs once to create a database schema. Numbering of change sets 0-N. Sometimes it becomes necessary to add something to these scripts. For example, a description for columns.I would like this script to be under table creation, but I can't do this because the next change set identifier is already taken.

I thought it would be nice if id was the date the script was executed, it would help solve my problem.

Comment: That kind of goes against the Liquibase "philosophy". Changesets are intended to be immutable once they have been deployed to anything other than your local dev database. If a change to the schema needs to be made, it is done by adding another changeset at the end of the changelog, not by modifying existing changesets. It sounds like you want to have your changelog organized by type, and that is also not something the tool has ever tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. The id, author, and path of a changeset must be immutable, as they are used to uniquely identify each changeset.